# Prediction interval for single future response

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I know the following results:

$\frac{RSS}{\sigma^{2}} \sim \chi^{2}_{n-r}$ where $r = rank(X)$ and $k$ is the degrees of freedom. Then, for any $c \in \mathbb{R^{p}} $, and when X has full rank, i.e. $rank(X) = p$, $\frac{\mathbf{c}^{T}\hat{\beta}-\mathbf{c}^{T}\beta}{\sqrt{\mathbf{c^{T}(X^{T}X)^{-1}\mathbf{c}\frac{RSS}{n-p}}}} \sim t_{n-p}$, following from $\frac{\mathbf{c^{T}}\hat{\beta}-\mathbf{c^{T}}\beta}{\mathbf{c^{T}}(X^{T}X)^{-1}\mathbf{c}\sigma^{2}} \sim N(0,1)$.

Suppose that we fit a linear model with design matrix X to obtain estimates $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ and $\hat{\sigma}^{2}$. For given covariates, $x_{*}$, the predicted response is $\hat{y}_{*} = x_{*}^{T}\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$.

We also know that $Var(x_{*}^{T}\hat{\beta}) = x_{*}^{T}(X^{T}X)^{-1}x_{*}\sigma^{2}$.

How, from the above, can I get the following result?
 A $100(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for a single future response is $\hat{y_{*}} \pm t_{n-p}^{(\frac{\alpha}{2})}\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{1+x_{*}^{T}(X^{T}X)^{-1}x_{*}}$? I've been stuck for ages.

Comment: To be precise, a confidence interval is an interval for the true value of a fixed population quantity, such as a parameter. It sounds like what you want is a prediction interval.

Comment: @Kodiologist Thank you - I changed the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wonder where did the extra $1$ come from. We have

$$E(\hat{Y}_* - Y_*)^2 = Var(\hat{Y}_*) + E(E(\hat{Y}_*) - Y_*)^2 = Var(\hat{Y}_*) + E(Y_* - x_*\beta)^2 = Var(\hat{Y}_*) + \sigma^2$$

Let's denote $Z = Y_* - \hat{Y}_*$. From Fisher's Theorem we know that $\hat{Y}_*$ is normally distributed, then so is $Z$. Now

$$\frac{Z - E(Z)}{\sqrt{Var(Z)}} = \frac{Y_* - \hat{Y}_* - 0}{\sqrt{E(\hat{Y}_* - Y_* - 0)^2}} = \frac{Y_* - \hat{Y}_*}{\sqrt{\sigma^2D_*}} \sim N(0,1)$$

Where $D_* = 1 + x_*^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_*$. Substituing estimator of $\sigma^2$, $S^2 = \frac{RSS}{n-p}$

$$\frac{Y_* - \hat{Y}_*}{\sqrt{D_*\frac{RSS}{n-p}}} \sim t(n-p)$$

and finally

$$P\Big(t_{\alpha/2} \le \frac{Y_* - \hat{Y}_*}{\sqrt{D_*\frac{RSS}{n-p}}} \le t_{1-\alpha/2}\Big) = 1 - \alpha$$

$$P\Big(\hat{Y}_*-t_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{D_*\frac{RSS}{n-p}} \le Y_* \le \hat{Y}_*+t_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{D_*\frac{RSS}{n-p}}\Big) = 1 - \alpha$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little further? I was kind of looking for a full explanation (derivation) from the above results.

Comment: @python_learner I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

Prediction intervals are wider because there is that extra uncertainty due to the new random observation.  See **Hahn and Meeker's Statistical Intervals** text published by Wiley for clear derivations and discussions of the various types of statistical intervals including Bayesian credible regions.

Comment: I was looking for the derivation mostly - could you provide it or at least point to a place in the text I can find it at?

Comment: While researching this I am sorry to say that my friend Gerry Hahn passed away.